# access bitmaps from speficied folder in android

Tags: android, file

I have successfully stored bitmap in sdcard/Pictures folder in android 2.X , using following code

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(path, "pic"+index+".jpg");
```

now, i want to retrieve all the images stored in that folder with out specifying name of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all the files in a directory with

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

You probably want to add a filefilter so that you only return jpg files you are interested in

File filters you can read about here
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FilenameFilter.html